# Three js Shader Material modify depth buffer

Tags: javascript, three.js

In Three js, I'm using a vertex shader to animate a large geometry.

I've also set up a Depth of Field effect on the output.  The problem is that the Depth of Field effect doesn't seem to know about the changed positioning created in my vertex shader.  It is responding as if the geometry is in the original position.

How can I update the depth information in my shader/material so that the DOF works correctly?  THREE.Material has a depthWrite property, but it doesn't seem to be that...

My depth of field pass works like this:

```
renderer.render( this.originalScene, this.originalCamera, this.rtTextureColor, true );

this.originalScene.overrideMaterial = this.material_depth;
renderer.render( this.originalScene, this.originalCamera, this.rtTextureDepth, true );
```

rtTextureColor and rtTextureDepth are both WebGLRenderTargets. For some reason rtTextureColor is correct, but rtTextureDepth is not

here is my vertex shader:

```
int sphereIndex = int(floor(position.x/10.));

            float displacementVal = displacement[sphereIndex].w;
            vec3 rotationDisplacement = displacement[sphereIndex].xyz;

            vNormal = normalize( normalMatrix * normal );
            vec3 vNormel = normalize( normalMatrix * viewVector );
            intensity = abs(pow( c - dot(vNormal, vNormel), p ));


            float xVal = (displacementVal*orbitMultiplier) * sin(timeValue*rotationDisplacement.x);
            float yVal = (displacementVal*orbitMultiplier) * cos(timeValue*rotationDisplacement.y);
            float zVal = 0;

            vec3 rotatePosition = vec3(xVal,yVal,zVal);

            vec3 newPos = (position-vec3((10.*floor(position.x/10.)),0,0))+rotatePosition;
            vec4 mvPosition;
            mvPosition = (modelViewMatrix *  vec4(newPos,1));

            vViewPosition = -mvPosition.xyz;
            vec4 p = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
            gl_Position = p;
```

Comment: are you referring to the normals

Comment: Think you need to re-calculate them in javascript, i have same issue with displacement map

Comment: No the normals are fine

Comment: I'm using a technique similar to this: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/million_letters/ but the depth of field (bokeh2) doesn't see the new positions

Comment: Is this.material_depth an instance of THREE.MeshDepthMaterial?

Comment: yes THREE.MeshDepthMaterial(); Sorry, that wasn't clear from the code

Comment: Can you show the vertex shader/material that animates the geometry? Likely you need to either configure MeshDepthMaterial differently, or create a custom ShaderMaterial like MeshDepthMaterial but with a vertex shader that animates like you need.

Comment: I've added the vertex shader code. It takes a load of merged spheres and animates them around a simple orbit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you set the scene override material (`this.originalScene.overrideMaterial = this.material_depth`) before rendering into `this.rtTextureDepth`, the renderer doesn't use your custom vertex shader. The scene override material is a [`THREE.MeshDepthMaterial`](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/MeshDepthMaterial), which includes its own vertex shader.

One thing to try is writing a [`THREE.ShaderMaterial`](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/ShaderMaterial) that works like `THREE.MeshDepthMaterial` but uses your custom vertex shader. Modifying built-in shaders isn't straightforward, but I would start from something like this:

```
var depthShader = THREE.ShaderLib['depth'];
var uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone(depthShader.uniforms);

var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: uniforms,
    vertexShader: /* your custom vertex shader */
    fragmentShader: depthShader.fragmentShader
});
```

You'll have to add the uniforms for your custom vertex shader and also set the uniforms for the built-in depth shaders; search `WebGLRenderer.js` in the three.js source for `MeshDepthMaterial`.